# How do I get typescript to infer the return type of a function based on the return type on a function of its arguments

Tags: typescript, type-inference, return-type

So this function is supposed to take in an array of objects that satisfy the `interface TransactionActionModel` . which means they must all have a function called "save" that receives arguments of the `interface SaveOptions` .

Currently the return type for this `saveUsingTransaction`  function is  `Promise<any[]>` .

```
interface TransactionActionModel {
  save: ({ session }: SaveOptions) => any;
}


const saveUsingTransaction = async (
    newEntities: TransactionActionModel[]
  ) => {
    const returnsArray = [];
    // Create Transaction
    const session = mongoDBWrapper.client.startSession();
    try {
      // Start Transaction
      session.startTransaction({});

      for (const entity of newEntities) {
        const resolve = await entity.save({ session });
        returnsArray.push(resolve);
      }

      // End Transaction
      await session.commitTransaction();

      return returnsArray;
    } catch (error) {
      await session.abortTransaction();

      throw error;
    } finally {
      await session.endSession();
    }
  };
```

Is there any way to get the return type of the `saveUsingTransaction`   to match the return type of the save function on the entities I pass into the `saveUsingTransaction` .

```
For Example

const person = {
 phone: "0233224444",
 save: ({session}):Person => {
      return this
     }
}

const cat = {
 weight: "30kg",
 save: ({session}): Animal => {
      return this
     }
}

const results = saveUsingTransaction([person, cat])

the type on the results variable should be ==> "[Person, Animal]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface should be generic:

```
interface TransactionActionModel<T> {
  save: ({ session }: SaveOptions) => T;
}
```

As well as your function:

```
const saveUsingTransaction = async <A extends TransactionActionModel<any>[]>(
  newEntities: [...A]
): { [K in keyof A]: ReturnType<A[K]["save"]> } => {
```

Use `[...A]` to infer `A` as a tuple, then use that tuple in the return type by mapping over its elements and changing them to the return type of their save function. TypeScript will infer the generic in the interface in `[...A]`.

[Simplified demo](https://tsplay.dev/w237xN)

Comment: I tried what was written above and it all seems to work, but I am now getting an error

"Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '{ [K in keyof A]: ReturnType<A[K]["save"]>; }'"

Comment: @CodetheDream Cast the return (`return returnsArray as ReturnType<typeof saveUsingTransaction<A>>`) or give `returnsArray` a type.

Comment: Thank you!. That worked!, but I had to cast it to unknown first. I love TypeScript too, where do I go to elevate my skills? any books?, link?